# How do you send text automatically? 

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

How do you automate text message in the broadcast receiver class.. I have a class implementing the broadcast receiver... I want to also automatically send a text message from this class too.. Is it possible? If so how??

I cant figure it out. and i've looked through android docs.

For example

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage []msgs = null;
    String str = "";

    if(bundle != null){
        Object[]pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            phonenumber +=  msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();




        }
        if(str.contains(houseNumber))
        Toast.makeText(context, phonenumber + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            phonenumber = MainActivity.phoneNumber;
            houseNumber = MainActivity.houseNumber;
```

IF it possible to send a text message automatically using smsManager in my if statement in the onReceive? If so how. Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 1):

use following code

```
SMSSender smsSender = new SMSSender(mContext);
smsSender.sendSMS(phoneNumber, messageString);
```